# Switch focus to table after adding an element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a button that when pressed, adds a new matrix to an array, which is rendered as a table of inputs. What I am trying to do is switch focus to the first/top-left element in the matrix after adding it to the array. I understand I can do this with refs, but I can't figure out how to do it.

https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-hellman-lx1cf

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Matrix = ({matrix}) => {
  return (
    <table>
      {matrix.map((row, _) => (
        <tr>
          {row.map((_, j) => (
            <td>
              <input size = {1}/>
            </td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  const [matrices, updateMatrices] = useState([]);

  const addMatrix = () => {
    updateMatrices(oldMatrices => {
      oldMatrices.push([[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]);
      return oldMatrices;
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => addMatrix()}> Add Matrix </button>
      {matrices.map(matrix => <Matrix matrix = {matrix}/>)}
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I doubt that html elements that can receive mouse or keyboard input (table being one of them) can have focus.

Comment: I am trying to switch focus to the input element rendered by the table

Comment: I just read your title and responded to it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply added this line to the matrix code:

```
<input
autoFocus = {r === 0 && c === 0 ? true: false} 
size={1} />
```